# Android Adding ListView items from JSON array

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have got one activity, but 3 layouts. ListView is a part of layout that is being displayed after loging in. That's why I can't set my ArrayAdapter onCreate, bacause my ListView is not initialized yet. I tried following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial, but I could not reproduce these steps. In this tutorial author did everything onCreate.

I tried doing it this way:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

...

    public class getcontacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

 ...HERE I AM FETCHING DATA...

 listItems.add(json_data.getString("login") + " " + derp);
 }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        getc = null;


        ac = new addcontacts();
        ac.execute(true);
```

And here is the code of addcontacts class:

```
 public class addcontacts extends ListActivity {


     protected void onCreate() {


         adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listItems);
         setListAdapter(adapter);

         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     }
     protected void execute(final Boolean success) {

    done = true;
     }


 }
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="188dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.53"
    android:text="Fetching contact list" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="106dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView doesn't contain anything. I checked in debugger that listItems have all items, so there is something wrong with adapter.

Comment: You don't instantiate Activities via explicit Contstructor as you have done. You should also pay attention to what you're writing, `onCreate()` needs to get a Bundle as an argument. Use `@Override` annotations, it will make like easier. Also, please use proper naming conventions and show us how each class is set up. If both the AsyncTask and the ListActivity are part of the same file, don't separate them.

Comment: Here is full code: http://pastebin.com/dA6dcZRv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your following approach:

1. In `Activity` class initialise `ListView` and `Adapter` with empty List.
2. Create subclass of `BaseAdapter` to get more control over it.
3. Pass `Adapter` and List via constructor of `Adapter`.
4. Pass `Adapter` and `List` in your `AsyncTask` subclass.
5. In your `doInBackground()` method perform fetching data from Server and
   add each item to `List`.
6. If you want to create **Lazy-Adapter** so each item added to `List`, call
   `publishProgress()` and in `onProgressUpdate()` method call
   `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
7. If not, after work is done, in `onPostExecute()` method call
   `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
8. Now it should works.

You are done.

Comment: Here is very similar example [`Android Custom ListView with Image and Text`](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) where data are parsed from XML and dynamically added into List with updating.

Comment: Seems complicated. Is there another simpler way?

Comment: its complicated yes but you don need to work with images and memory. You need only look how parsing and updating adapter, nothing more.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll look into it, but I suppose it's going to take me few days. x.x